# Is it possible to permission specific resources to specific users on Google Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

Is it possible to permission specific resources to specific users?

Example:

- I want John Doe to only be able to modify one specific cluster, but not any other clusters.
- I want Jane Doe to be able to write to certain buckets but not all buckets.

Comment: I understand there is IAM, but can IAM be broken down into cluster granularity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to be able to limit access to specific resources.  This can be done through IAM. Here is a great place to start that explains how this is done: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview

Comment: I understand there is IAM, but can IAM be broken down into cluster granularity?